# Creating the check box and the text value in windows form

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

In the windows form how to dynamically create the check box and the label based on certain conditions.

Comment: `new CheckBox()` and `new Label()`?

Comment: you need to mention the location of the `control` as well.

Answer (score 1):

After creating instance of the controls that you want to add don't forget to add them to the form Controls property, try this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool condition = true;
    if (condition)
    {

        Label l_newOne = new Label()
        {
            Text = "Label: ",
            Location = new Point(10, 30)

        };

        CheckBox chckb_newOne = new CheckBox()
        {
            Text = "Correct",
            Location = new Point(50, 25)
        };

        this.Controls.AddRange(new Control[] { chckb_newOne, l_newOne });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (CertainCondition)
{
    Children.Add(new CheckBox());
}
```